# C# Compare 2 strings, sorting, put into array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, compare, bubble-sort

hi im formulating my question now better.

in the foreach command i get for temp(save variable) values in an array. The values that i save in temp are from the datagridview cells.

in the next step, in the for command, i want to compare 2 strings, the string and the next string, if the fist string is bigger than the second, i want to change their positions. But there is the problem, they dont change positions they even get an empty value, and i cant understand why they get an empty value.

Im thinking that they get an empty value because of the foreach command, the index [i] just stays the same, but if i would put in i = i+1, the command would be out of bound.

Thank you

senc. NIko

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)     
{
    if (row.Cells[i].Value == null)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("This row is empty");
        break;
    }
    if (row.Cells[i].Value != null)
    {
        temp = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
        UnsortArray[i] = temp;
        i = i + 1;

    }
}

for (int a = 0; a < MaxZeilen; a++)
{
    if (i < MaxZeilen)
    {
        *if (String.Compare(UnsortArray[a], UnsortArray[a + 1]) > 0) 
        {
            UnsortArray[a] = temp;
            UnsortArray[a + 1] = temp2;
            temp = UnsortArray[a + 1];
            temp2 = UnsortArray[a];
        }*
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < MaxZeilen; i++)
{
    UnsortArray[i] = SortArray[i];
    MessageBox.Show(UnsortArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to sort all strings or just swap strings near each other? Your code doesn't sort all strings. {"22", "33", "11"} will become {"22", "11", "33"}

Comment: are you sure, that UnsortArray contains right strings after foreach code?

Comment: yes it was mentioned to sort the strings. but not with numbers, with names. like {"Pepsi" "Cola" "Fanta" "Orangejuice"} should become (alphabetic) {"Cola" "Fanta" "Orangejuice" "Pepsi"}. My mentor said it would work with compare, but im not sure..

Comment: Please read some articles about sorting algorithms http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: And in your foreach loop you read 1 value from 1 row and each time it is new column. Is it ok?

Comment: no, i just have 1 column, just multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're backwards, assigning the array to your temp variables before assigning the temp variables:

```
UnsortArray[a] = temp;
UnsortArray[a + 1] = temp2;
temp = UnsortArray[a + 1];
temp2 = UnsortArray[a];
```

Try:

```
temp = UnsortArray[a + 1];
temp2 = UnsortArray[a];
UnsortArray[a] = temp;
UnsortArray[a + 1] = temp2;
```

And you've done it again here `UnsortArray[i] = SortArray[i];`. I think you mean `SortArray[i] = UnsortArray[i];`

Comment: unfortunetlly it doesnt works, changes nothing -.- BUT THANK YOU

Comment: ok i understand now whats going on, thank you for your help. but the problem still exists, as you can see i created a MessageBox for showing the values, and all boxes are empty. so sth is wrong, im searching further!

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with the following code block

```
int i= 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)     
{
    if (row != null)
    {
        temp = row.ToString();
        UnsortArray[i] = temp;
        i = i + 1;
    }
}


for (int a = 0; a < MaxZeilen; a++)
{
    if (String.Compare(UnsortArray[a], UnsortArray[a + 1]) > 0) 
    {
        temp = UnsortArray[a + 1];             
        UnsortArray[a + 1] = UnsortArray[a];
        UnsortArray[a] = temp;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < MaxZeilen; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(UnsortArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: i have tried this already, but the code doesnt change anything. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: did you notice that i have removed the outer if condition ?

Comment: yes i did. your explaination was usefull for me, i would give up an up but i dont have enough reputations -.- No it didnt helped, as already said :&

Comment: are you setting the value of i above foreach loop ?

Comment: this is the case when you are comparing values of different columns in a datagrid. if you are try to compare values of same columns and different row then you need a different construct.

Comment: No that also doesnt work, as i said, the code line : i = i+1;  get the if statement into an out of bound.

Comment: i guess you are need to compare values in different rows instead of different columns. i'll give you code for that hold on for a minute

Comment: I have edited the code, this is the case when you need to compare rows in a column.

Comment: thats not possible Ankit, row[0] cant be compared with null, its systemform

Comment: i will try now row[0].Value != null //€dit: doesnt work. ouuh so heavy to me ;(

Answer (score 1):

```
    temp = UnsortArray[a + 1];    

    UnsortArray[a + 1] = UnsortArray[a];

    UnsortArray[a] = temp;
```

instead of

```
          UnsortArray[a] = temp;

          UnsortArray[a + 1] = temp2;

          temp = UnsortArray[a + 1];

          temp2 = UnsortArray[a];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why using an array and not a List ?

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) tells about sorting lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some improvements to your code.  You had an error at the top that could cause a infinite loop and just use the Array.Sort method.  If you want it to sort differently, add an IComparable interface.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)     
{
     if (row.Cells[i].Value == null)
     {
          //MessageBox.Show("This row is empty");
          i++;
          break;
     }
     else (row.Cells[i].Value != null)
     {
          UnsortArray[i] = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
          i++;
     }
}  

Array.Sort(UnsortArray);
SortArray = UnsortArray;
```

Comment: i dont know the sort method of array.sort. as mentioned i need to create an bubblesorting namesort programm.

Comment: Completely unrelated to this answer, but just wanted to message you: re your [edit here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1581706/3) - no, that is incorrect: you can have as many `using` statements as you want, with a single set of braces. The code compiles perfectly "as is"

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I took your code and compiled it, and it does compile.  Thanks for the info.  I also found another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2520086/98802) that explains that in more detail.  I couldn't find any info about this on the Microsoft site. My initial mistake might have been putting a semicolon after the using statements, and that would _not_ compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<String> itemList = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value = null)
        {
            itemList.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    itemList.Sort();
    string[] SortedArray = itemList.ToArray();

    for (int j = 0; j < SortedArray.Length; j++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(SortedArray[j]);
    }
```

and if this code doesn't work, than add

```
foreach(string item in itemList)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item);
}
```

after first foreach loop and check the values

Comment: if (row.Cells[0].Value == null)  ---> again null exception problem on itemlist.add code

Answer (score 1):

```
int MaxArrayCount = 0; 
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)    
{ 
MaxArrayCount += row.Cells.Count;
 }
 string[] UnsortArray= new string[MaxArrayCount];



int cnt = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++ )
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[i].Value != null)
                        {
                            temp = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();

                            UnsortArray[cnt] = temp;

                            cnt++;
                        } 
                    }

                }



for (int b = 1; b < UnsortArray.Count; b++)
{    
  for (int a = 0; a < UnsortArray.Count - 1; a++)   
     {    

    if (String.Compare(UnsortArray[a], UnsortArray[a + 1]) > 0)
     {

      temp = UnsortArray[a + 1];

      UnsortArray[a + 1] = UnsortArray[a];

      UnsortArray[a] = temp;

    }    
  }    
}


for (int i = 0; i < MaxZeilen; i++)
{
MessageBox.Show(UnsortArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: No doesnt work, i dont know how often do i say, i cant ++cnt, if i count cnt++ i get an out of bound, why does nobody understand this? THANK YOU

Comment: you cant get out of bound for cnt++ , until you have UnsortedArray[] limited in length  , use:

  int MaxArrayCount = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                MaxArrayCount += row.Cells.Count;
            }

 string[] UnsortArray= new string[MaxArrayCount];

Comment: ok you were right!!!! You solved it, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!! Im now trying to get the values into another datagrid, little bit difficult but im optimistic =) THUMBS UP FOR HIM!!!!! ty

Comment: SURE, please do it, i have tried it yesterday, but i have too less reputations

Comment: i guess now you have enough repo to mark this as an answer. lol i'm being annoying i know, but still :D could you? D:D: